# How to pass parameter while executing command in Groovy Script

Tags: groovy

```
command = ["C:/Users/Desktop/try.bat"] 
def command1=command    
def cmd = command1.execute()    
cmd.waitFor()
```

This is my code. But I need to pass 4 arguments to `try.bat`. Out of these one argument is optional. How to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

add more items in the array

```
["command", "param1", "param2"].execute()
```

as stated in the official docs http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy

Comment: Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'demo_groovy1Flow1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.module.scripting.component.ScriptComponent] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable] while setting bean property 'script';

Comment: yes, without adding parameter, the code is working fine

Comment: then show us the new code. it's hard to guess with such a generic error message

Comment: i got the solution. command will not be inside []. But how to pass optional argument. I tried arg* but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try

```
def command = """C:/Users/Desktop/try.bat arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4"""
```

as the official docs provided suggest http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy